# Mute specific audio inputs with Win MMDevice API

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I have a very specific requirement where I need to mute the "Auxiliary" input.  I am already using the [Windows Core Audio APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784(v=vs.85).aspx) like EndpointVolume & MMDevice.

### Scenario

I need to mute the auxiliary output volume here in order to achieve the desired effect. 
Pictured below is the audio device and it's properties.

[image: Figure 1]

### Issues

- Using `MMDeviceEnumerator` it doesn't appear that the endpoint depicted above includes any of the "output volume levels" displayed in the second half of that screenshot.
- Muting the actual recording device (*Auxiliary*) does not actually mute what is heard.
- This must be as simple as possible with as little human interaction as possible. The environment will be controlled entirely via the application as it is a kiosk. The screenshots below indicates what I am referring to when I say *"auxiliary recording device which when muted, does nothing"*:

[image: Figure 2]

Is there a hidden place that the [*Levels* tab's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEkUW.png) individual "input output levels" exist?  I cannot find it anywhere within MMDevice which means I am currently unable to mute this device through code. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed (most likely) the windows SDK. You can have a look at this example:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\multimedia\audio\EndpointVolume

Does that enumerate your device that plays the auxiliary input?